# Как сохранить полученный токен для авторизации?

Tags: reactjs

```
  import React from 'react';
  import axios from 'axios';

  import {Table} from 'reactstrap';

  class Newpage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){

      super(props);

      this.state = {
        token: '',
        items:[]
      }
    } 

    componentDidMount(){
      axios.post(`https://gentle-escarpment-19443.herokuapp.com/v1/users/auth`, 
        {
          email:"user1@email.com",
          password: '!password!'
        },
        {headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }})
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              token: res.data.access_token
            })
          });

      axios.get("https://gentle-escarpment-19443.herokuapp.com/v1/articles", {
        headers: { 
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.state.token
        }
      })
        .then((response)=>{
          this.setState({
            items: response.data
          })
        });

    }

    render() {
      console.log(this.state.token)

      let items = this.state.items.map((item) => {
        return(
          <tr key={item.id}>
            <td>{item.id}</td>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td>{item.price}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      });

      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.token}
          <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {items}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Newpage;
```

Comment: localstorage -_-

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать или что почитать?

Comment: токен сохраните в `localstorage`.Потом проверяйте при каждом входе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас запрос авторизации асинхронный, ему нужно время, чтобы выполниться. Плюс время на добавление в state через setState. А запрос статей выполняется ещё до получения токена, поэтому и не проходит.

Вот это будет работать:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import {Table} from 'reactstrap';

class Newpage extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      token: '',
      items: []
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    const authResponse = await axios.post(
      'https://gentle-escarpment-19443.herokuapp.com/v1/users/auth',
      {
        email: 'user1@email.com',
        password: '!password!'
      },
      {
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    );

    const token = authResponse.data.access_token

    const articlesResponse = await axios.get(
      'https://gentle-escarpment-19443.herokuapp.com/v1/articles',
      {
        headers: { 
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
      }
    );

    const items = articlesResponse.data;

    this.setState({
      items,
      token
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {token, items} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {token}
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {
              items.map(item => (
                <tr key={item.id}>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>{item.price}</td>
                </tr>
              ))
            }
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Newpage;
```